# Visual Studio Disassembly Syntax Highlighter

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Is there a disassembly highlighter for Visual Studio? I say this because look at the difference between these 2 disassemblers:

Visual Studio: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QPCk.png

IDA Pro: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1PfD.png

Now at the least I'd like a syntax highlighter for Visual Studio, because it's just so UGLY! Also, please don't say ASMHighlighter because that is only supported when writing assembly, not disassembling. Thanks, Stevie.

Answer (score 0):

The VS extension [AsmDude](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude) version 1.9.0.0 provides syntax highlighting (and more) for the disassembly window for visual studio 2015 and 2017